# I'm getting this error but I tried everything. TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, syntax, floating-point

I'm having an issue with running this simple calculator. Every time I run this program, I get this error:

```
f = a * l
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Does anyone notice my error and how I can correct it?

```
while True:
print("///Calculator///")
print("======================================")
mq = float(input("Market Quote: "))
if mq==0:
 break
a = input("Balance: ")

l = input("Lev: ")

if not l:
    l = 500
else:
    l = float(l)
    0
p = input("Other: ")

if not p:
    p = 70
else:
    p = float(p)
#-------------------------------------

f = a * l 

q = f / l 
mr = q * mq  
so = 0.40     
mm = mr * so  

k = p * 10    
b = a - mm  
x = b / k  
h = x / 8 
u = round(h, 2)

o = x * mq
j = o / l
c = round(j)
```

Comment: `a` is a `str` - perhaps you meant to call `a = float(input(...))`

Comment: The error is that you can't multiply a sequence by a float.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert all numerical inputs to floats or ints if you want to do numerical calculations on them. You forgot `a` and `p`:

```
a = float(input("Balance: "))
...
p = float(input("Other: "))
```

---

Two general tips for the future: give your variables meaningful names (you can skip vowels or whatever for speed, but apart from indexes, one letter variables aren't great) and read error messages! Here `'can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float''` means exactly that! The result of any call to `input()` is a string (a sequence type) and when you multiply a sequence by an integer, Python interprets that as you wanting to repeat it, as in:

```
>>> 'a' * 4
'aaaa'
```

But what is it supposed to do with a float? I certainly don't know and neither does it:

```
>>> 'a' * 4.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

And if the worst comes to the worst and you can't interpret Python's complaints, then you still have the line number - go there and see that all that is being done is: `f = a * l` so your next step should be to analyse what are `a`, what are `l` and why can't Python multiply them!

My point is, yes debugging is hard, but it is a skill, and trying things isn't always the right way to go - sometimes being methodical speeds up the process.